krenel module call_usermodehelper issues
I want to call mknod in my kernel driver. but never work.
I tested some simple command, but all failed.
my system is fedora 40, kernel 6.9.7.
here is my test code :
static int __init call_usermodehelper_init(void)
{
    int ret = -1;   
    char path[] = "/bin/mkdir";
    char *argv[] = {path, "-p", "/tmp/new_dir", NULL};

    char *envp[] = {"HOME=/", 
                "SHELL=/bin/bash",
                "TERM=linux", 
                "PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin", 
                NULL};
    printk("call_usermodehelper module is starting..!\n");
    ret = call_usermodehelper(path, argv, envp, UMH_WAIT_PROC);
    printk("ret=%d\n", ret);
    return 0;
}
module_init(call_usermodehelper_init);

and the code never succeed.
after I load the ko, no /tmp/touchX.txt is found.
I have changed the argv many times for these days, and no success, the func returns  -2/-13/256..
but when I compile and run the ko on other linux, Ubuntu/rhel,  the call_usermodehelper can run normally.
can anybody tell me why call_usermodehelper always fail on fedora?
I have tested it on other systems and it works fine.
I wonder why it doesn't work on the fedora system

You wrote "my test code is like this". If this is only similar to what you actually used, this may hide or add errors. Please [edit] your question and show code you actually ran on your system. Create a [mre].

I have updated the code.

The problem has been solved. The reason was selinux. I set selinux to disabled and the function call_usermodehelper  can be executed successfully.
